# Copy and paste in terminal termux:float

Tags: terminal

I know how to copy and paste in termux (https://termux.com/) but it is not the same for termux:float. How to copy and paste in termux:float?

Answer (score 1):

There's no native functionality according to [this github issue](https://github.com/termux/termux-float/issues/1).

However, you can write a workaround by changing your tmux config as follows:

```
bind V run-shell "termux-clipboard-get >~/.tmux-buffer-tmp" \; load-buffer -b tmp-copy-buffer ~/.tmux-buffer-tmp \; paste-buffer -b tmp-copy-buffer -d \; run-shell -b "rm ~/.tmux-buffer-tmp"
bind C save-buffer ~/.tmux-buffer-tmp \; run-shell "cat ~/.tmux-buffer-tmp | termux-clipboard-set " \; run-shell -b "rm ~/.tmux-buffer-tmp"
```

Comment: Now I am not using termux, however thank you for your answer.